# How deeply we can extract information with gps and google maps

Tags: google-maps, android-gps

Is it possible to grab all this information by using google maps and gps?

- Addresses of the current location
- Names of the locations(Resturants,Hospitals,Gas Stations)
- Phone numbers related to those places

Answer (score 0):

I find out the answer by myself. If you want to do this stuff in android then you have to work with "Google Places API" that shares almost the same data they have on the google maps.